# How can I stop a Linux timer when GDB stops a process

Tags: linux, timer

In a Linux program, I have a number of threads within one process. Some of the threads are calling **clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &time)**; in order to calculate timeout values, e.g. to see if some actions have completed within time or not. This works perfect if the system is running normally. But if the process is stopped by some GDB breakpoint, the Linux system timer continues counting in the background and if GDB continues executing the process, all timeout values are exceeded.

Can anybody tell me if there is a way to start/stop a (process-local)timer while GDB is halting the process because of a breakpoint ?

As an alternative I can create my own timer system that will be triggered by a signal from a system timer, but then I need to block these signals while GDB has stopped the process. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know is slightly problematic...

Change all uses of CLOCK_MONOTONIC to CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID

> ```
>   CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID (since Linux 2.6.12)
>          A clock that measures (user and system) CPU time consumed by (all of the threads in) the calling process.
> ```

It stops when gdb stops the process.

I say slightly problematic for a couple of reasons....

- It doesn't play nice with pthreads on a multicore.
- It doesn't work correctly when you block for I/O
- It doesn't work correctly with sleep() or sigsuspend()

As a "help me debug hack" it sort of works, so maybe make it switchable.